# Cometd filter data for specific client in channel

Tags: java, comet, cometd

I'm designing a system using comet where there is a common channel where data getting published. I need to filter the data using some conditions based on client subscription details. Can anyone tell how I can do this? I thought I can do this using DataFilter.

```
Channel.addDataFilter(DataFilter filter);
```

Is this the correct way? If so any sample code to achieve this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `Channel.addDataFilter(DataFilter)` method, but you can achieve the same results in a different way.

First, have a look at the available `DataFilter` implementations [already available](https://github.com/cometd/cometd/tree/2.6.x/cometd-java/cometd-java-server/src/main/java/org/cometd/server/filter).

Then it's enough that you add a `DataFilterMessageListener` to the channel you want to filter data on, and specify one or more `DataFilter` to the `DataFilterMessageListener`.

You can find an example of this in the CometD demos shipped with the CometD distribution, for example [here](https://github.com/cometd/cometd/blob/2.6.x/cometd-java/cometd-java-examples/src/main/java/org/cometd/examples/ChatService.java).

The right way to add the `DataFilterMessageListener` is during channel initialization, as it is done in the example linked above through a `@Configure` annotation, or equivalently via `ServerChannel.Initializer`.

Finally, have a look at how messages are processed on the server from the documentation: http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#concepts_message_processing.
It is important to understand that modifications made by `DataFilter` are seen by all subscribers.

Comment: Thanks. Will try out in the way you advised and give my feedback.

Comment: I checked the links. I found it is possible to do the filtering in data in common using them. But I need to stop sending data in the same channel if there is no need to send to some specific client. Simply I need to stop data from sending for some clients & enable for some other. Any help on this? Thanks for the links once again.

Comment: @Suda if you need to send data differently to different subscribers to the same channel, then you cannot use listeners or APIs such as `ServerChannel.publish(...)` because those will send the same message to all subscribers. You need to use `ServerSession.deliver(...)` instead, taking the list of the `ServerSession` from the channel's subcribers. Since you're iterating over the subscribers, you can apply/modify your messages for each `ServerSession` by applying the `DataFilter` manually. Finally, if you return `false` from a `MessageListener`, the message processing will be aborted.

Comment: Thanks @sbordet. I'll follow the way you suggested.

Comment: @Bordet, I was able to implement this successfully. But in comparison to the publishing method, is there any performance difference in doing this way? Simply asked, which one of the following is having better performance? Sending to all subscribed clients using publish() method OR iterate clients & send using deliver method? Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @Bordet, that sounds great! I was worried whether I'm loosing some performance by iterating manually for filtering. Thanks for all your help! much appreciated :)